# How can I bind an array of returned Firebase elements to my AngularJS view (via a controller)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

My HTML is

```
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <td>
        <a ui-sref="englishDetail({id: question.id})">
          {{ question.id }}
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ question.instruction }}</td>
      <td>{{ question.questionText }}</td>
      <td>{{ question.level }}</td>
      <td>
        <a ui-sref="passageDetail({id: question.passageId})">
          {{ question.passageId }}
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

In my controller, I have

```
var fbase;

$scope.questions = [];

fbase = new Firebase("https://my.firebaseio.com");

fbase.child("questions").orderByChild("subject").equalTo("english").once("value", function(questionsSnapshot) {
  $scope.questions = [];
  questionsSnapshot.forEach(function(questionSnapshot) {
    $scope.questions.push({
      id: questionSnapshot.key(),
      instruction: questionSnapshot.val().instruction,
      questionText: questionSnapshot.val().questionText,
      level: questionSnapshot.val().level,
      passageId: questionSnapshot.val().passageId
    });
  });
  return $scope.$apply();
});
```

It somehow seems unnecessary to have to iterate over the returned object to achieve what I am trying to do. Is there a better / more native way of doing this? I've looked into the supposed `three way data binding` on the Firebase doc site but that doesn't show how to do it if you are filtering objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Use AngularFire for synchronized collections.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function MyController($scope, rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = rootRef.child('questions');
  // handles $digest loop and synchronizing to an array
  $scope.questions = $firebaseArray(ref);
}
```

Comment: Can I use this with filtering as well?

Comment: Yep. Just make a query from the ref and pass it into the $firebaseArray.